# How can I handle a confusionMatrix error when it says my Data is null

Tags: r, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I am trying to run a random forests analysis in R and it works well when I fit the model and predict it on the test group but when I run the confusionMatrix it gives me the following error:

`Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : all arguments must have the same length`

load the test and training data

```
trainData <- read.csv("./pml-training.csv")
testData <- read.csv("./pml-testing.csv")
dim(trainData)
dim(testData)
```

Data cleaning - Here, variables with nearly zero variance or that are almost always NA,
and the columns containing summary statistics or irrelevant data will be removed.

```
trainClean <- trainData[,colMeans(is.na(trainData))< .9] 
trainClean <- trainData[,-c(1:7)] 
nvz <- nearZeroVar(trainClean)
trainClean <- trainClean[,-nvz]
dim(trainClean)
```

Split the data into training (70%) and validation (30%)

```
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=trainClean$classe, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
train <- trainClean[inTrain,]
valid <- trainClean[-inTrain,]
# Create a control for 3 fold validation
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=3, verboseIter = FALSE)
```

## Building the models

### Random Forests

```
# Fit the model on train using random forest
modFit <- train(classe~., data=train, method="rf", trControl=control, tuneLength=5, na.action=na.omit)
modFit
modPredict<- predict(modFit, valid, na.action=na.omit) # predict on the valid data set.
# Turn valid$classe into a factor and check it
valid$classe <- as.factor(valid$classe)
modCM <- confusionMatrix(modPredict, as.factor(valid$classe))
modCM
table(modPredict, valid$classe)
```

When I check the length of modPredict it = 122, and valid$classe = 5885. If I try dim on modPredict, I get NULL. I have tried using na.action=na.omit on the prediction chunk. I have also tried NOT using na.action=na.omit on the prediction or the fit chunks.
I checked the test and valid data sets where I split the data using:

````
```length(train); length(valid); length(valid$classe); nrow(valid); nrow(train)```
````

The output is:

```
[1] 94
[1] 94
[1] 5885
[1] 5885
[1] 13737
```

I have been struggling with this problem and similar problems on my decision tree chunk as well. I don't want people to do my homework for me, but I could use a hint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have `na.action=na.omit`, so you are dropping rows with `NA` values (if any) from the validation set to make predictions. This means there are fewer predictions than rows in `valid`.

Comment: `dim` will return `NULL` on anything 1-dimensional. But if you compare `length(modPredict)` with `nrow(valid)`, I think you'll see the discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you. I see it. I ran na.omit separately on both train and valid, but I am getting the same discrepancy. (apologies, I am learning.) How can I fix this?

Comment: A good potential workaround might be to define `valid_filter <- na.omit(valid)`, and then run predictions on that and use it to make your confusion matrix.

Comment: I figured it out on my own! It was a problem with the data cleaning. I removed NAs then I removed some columns, but I removed the columns on the original data frame not the renamed one. I fixed it and every thing is fine. Except I feel silly. Thanks for you help Gregor!